# Decompile method from assembly (ICSharpCode)

Tags: .net, decompiling, mono.cecil, icsharpcode

I'm trying to decompile a method programmatically using ICSharpCode. I'm able to decompile the entire type, but whenever I try to decompile a single method, I get a null reference exception. The approach is much like this question [ICSharpCode.Decompiler + Mono.Cecil -> How to generate code for a single method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811448/icsharpcode-decompiler-mono-cecil-how-to-generate-code-for-a-single-method)

The exception is thrown when invoking astBuilder.AddMethod. Any idea of what I'm missing. Or maybe recommendations for a different framework?

Thanks in advance!

Stacktrace:

> at
>   ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.NameVariables.AssignNamesToVariables(DecompilerContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters, IEnumerable`1 variables, ILBlock
>   methodBody)    at
>   ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.CreateMethodBody(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)    at
>   ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.CreateMethodBody(MethodDefinition
>   methodDef, DecompilerContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder.CreateMethodBody(MethodDefinition
>   method, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder.CreateMethod(MethodDefinition
>   methodDef)    at
>   ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder.AddMethod(MethodDefinition
>   method)    at CodeFlow.Decompile.DecompileMethod(String assemblyPath,
>   String assemblyFile, String typeName, String methodName) in
>   C:\Arbejdsfiler\DCFServices\Tools\CustomFxCopRules\CustomCodeAnalysis\CodeFlow\Decompile.cs:line
>   69

Comment: Nobody been messing around with decompiling programmatically?

Comment: check my answer in the original article: [ICSharpCode.Decompiler + Mono.Cecil -> How to generate code for a single method?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811448/icsharpcode-decompiler-mono-cecil-how-to-generate-code-for-a-single-method

Comment: Torsten - works like a charm! Create an answer and mark it.